# Get page source code with WWW::Selenium?

Tags: perl, selenium

I am trying to get the source code of a web-page. I tried using LWP::Simple, but it didn't help. I installed WWW::Selenium package using ppm and but get the error "undefined subroutine &main::get_html_source called at line 6."

here's the code I used.

```
use LWP::UserAgent;
use HTTP::Request;
use HTTP::Response;
use WWW::Selenium;
$url="http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/25582922";
$out = getHtmlSource($url) or die "could not get the url $url \n";
open(file, ">testing_ncbi.txt");
print file "$out\n";
```

Any help?

Comment: show what you tried with LWP::Simple - it (or LWP::UserAgent) is the appropriate tool to use

Comment: Thanks , LWP :: Simple works well for the link $url="http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/25582922"; However, when I tried the url     $url="source-code:http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/25582922"; , it doesn't work

Comment: why are you trying with "source-code:"?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Selenium::Remote::Driver](https://metacpan.org/pod/Selenium::Remote::Driver) module and do the below

```
use Selenium::Remote::Driver;

my $driver = Selenium::Remote::Driver->new;
$driver->get('http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/25582922');
print $driver->get_page_source();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LWP::Simple`, like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use LWP::Simple;

my $url = 'http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/25582922';

my $out = get $url;
open my $fh, '>', 'testing_ncbi.html' or die $!;
print $fh $out, "\n";
```

and `testing_ncbi.html` will contain the HTML source code

I don't know where you got the idea to add `source-code:` but it doesn't mean anything in a URL